# Does the Leray-Serre-Atiyah-Hirzebruch Spectral Sequence go under a different name?

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question, convention, spectral-sequences

This is more of a naming convention question than anything else. I am reading up on spectral sequences mainly from the book *Lecture Notes in Algebraic Topology by Davis and Kirk*. Now in this book the existence of what is labelled as the *Leray-Serre-Atiyah-Hirzebruch Spectral Sequence* is stated as:

> **Theorem:** Let $F \to E \to B$ be a fibration with $B$ a path-connected CW-Complex. Let $G_{\star}$ be an additive homology theory. Then there exists a spectral sequence $$H_p(B, G_q(F)) \cong E^2_{p, q} \implies G_{p+q}(E).$$

The authors, *Davis and Kirk* refer the reader to the book *Elements of Homotopy Theory by George Whitehead* for the construction of the *Leray-Serre-Atiyah-Hirzebruch Spectral Sequence*. However in *Whitehead's* book the *Leray-Serre-Atiyah-Hirzebruch Spectral Sequence* seems to just be called the *Spectral Sequence of a Fibration*.

From skimming through Whitehead's book and Allen Hatcher's book *Spectral Sequences in Algebraic Topology* it seems that the *Serre Spectral Sequence* is just a special case of the *Leray-Serre-Atiyah-Hirzebruch Spectral Sequence* when we take $G_{\star}$ to be ordinary homology with integer coefficients.

However it Hatcher's book (on page 18 under "Generalized Homology Theories), he mentions that one can generalize the *Serre Spectral Sequence* to arbitrary cohomology theories. The spectral sequence attained which he doesn't give a name to, I assume, would be the *Leray-Serre-Atiyah-Hirzebruch* spectral sequence above. He then goes on to say that the *Atiyah-Hirzebruch Spectral Sequence* is a special case of this unnamed spectral sequence in the case when the fibre $F$ is a point.

My assumption seems to be further validated by the [Wikipedia article on the Atiyah-Hirzebruch Spectral Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atiyah%E2%80%93Hirzebruch_spectral_sequence) which states that Atiyah and Hirzebruch found an (unnamed) generalization of the *Serre Spectral Sequence* (which I again guess would be the *Leray-Serre-Atiyah-Hirzebruch Spectral Sequence* above) of which the *Serre Spectral Sequence* is a special case when one takes singular homology (or since singular homology is isomorphic to ordinary homology with integer coefficients for CW complexes). Further still it states that the *Atiyah-Hirzebruch Spectral Sequence* is a special case of this unnamed spectral sequence when the fibre $F$ is a point.

It seems then that both the unnamed spectral sequences mentioned above are what is referred to in Davis and Kirk's book as the *Leray-Serre-Atiyah-Hirzebruch Spectral Sequence*, is this correct? Furthermore is the *Leray-Serre-Atiyah-Hirzebruch Spectral Sequence* equivalent to the *Spectral Sequence of a Fibration*?

If so then what is the naming convention for this spectral sequence, is it usually called the *Spectral Sequence of a Fibration* as in Whitehead's book or the *Leray-Serre-Atiyah-Hirzebruch Spectral Sequence* as in Davis and Kirk's book. In other words which name is most often used to reference this spectral sequence in books, articles, papers etc.?

Comment: As you have discovered, "the" naming convention sometimes does not even exist.